# A Version of Fubini-Tonelli Theorem for Hilbert Space Valued Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I'm currently working on a project in which we define a new type of integral. And I'm trying to intechange the integral with expectation, something like $\mathbb{E} \left[ (\mathcal{N})\int f dW \right]=(\mathcal{N})\int \left[ \mathbb{E} f dW \right]$, where $\mathcal{N}$ denoted the defined integral, $f$ is an operator-valued stochastic process and $W$ a Hilbert-space valued $Q$-Weiner Process. Under which conditions can I do such thing?

What I give might be vague. But, could this involve something like Fubini-Tonelli Theorem? I haven't also read a version of this theorem in for function in infinite dimensions. If there is, please cite. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: I am significantly out of my depth here, but do you know anything about the [Bochner integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral)?

Comment: Somehow @TheoBendit :)

Comment: I think it is true for Bochner and Pettis integrals. Evaluate both sides at a continuous linear functional.

Comment: @Crunchy I am interested in the same type of problem, have you published anything, may you share a reference? TIA

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Theorem you need is Theorem 2 in Chapter X in the book    [The Bochner Integral](https://books.google.it/books?id=XQqoAAAAIAAJ) isbn 9780124958500